# Laravel 4.2 Queue::push IronMQ timeout option

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have searched around but unable to figure out how to pass an options array with queue::push to allow ironmq more time to process a queue as it takes longer than 60 seconds. When 60 seconds pass, it is firing the queue again. I have tried the following:

Queue::push("SomeClass@someMethod", array('variable' => $variable), null, array('timeout' => 3600));

Which I found described here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/3555 which I was hoping that would work but doesn't. This is laravel 4.2 and just trying to pass a timeout option to ironmq.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I reread the post from the link above and tried Taylor's suggestion and it worked for me. Here is what I did to prevent ironmq from firing the job again.

```
Route::post('queue/api', function()
{
    $response = Response::make("Skip Timeout", 200);
    $response->send();

    return Queue::marshal();
});
```

This prevents ironmq from firing the job again if it takes longer than 60 seconds.